# PHP Times Value by Percentage

Tags: php

How do i *(Times) Percentage ?

```
$variable = 2 ; 

and i wanted it to times 5.3% , how should i do it ?

$variable * 1.5%; < caused error
```

============================

Think a new ways thanks to @Barmar

By Adding new variable s

$percentage = 0.53;
$finalprice = $variable + ($variable *  $percentage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert a percentage to a number by dividing by 100, e.g. `5.3% = 0.053`.

Increasing a number by a percentage is the same as multiplying by `1 + percentage/100`. So if you want to increase by `5.3%`, you multiply by `1.053`

```
$variable *= 1.053;
```

Comment: thanks , from the answer u provided , able to think another ways by adding a new variable .

$percentage = 0.53; 

so the final would be
$finalprice = $variable + ($variable*$percentage);

Comment: Or `$finalprice = $variable * (1 + $percentage)`